Need help understanding the proof of Szemeredi's lemma using Los's theorem
I've found these lecture notes: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~chernikov/teaching/16F-MATH223M/CombinatoricsNotes2.pdf
I'm trying to understand the proof of theorem 2.1. (regularity lemma), but it seems like the entirety of the proof (on page 12) is handwaved away. I understand the general idea, but the details elude me.
We assume that the theorem does not hold, hence we can find, for a fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ a sequence of graphs, such that no $\varepsilon$-regular partition exists. We take the ultraproduct, pretty standard stuff. From here on I'm lost.
Usually when taking an ultraproduct, we refer to first order properties. Which first order property is needed here? Can we express the existence of $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$-regular finite partition via a first order formula?
Could somebody write out the proof in more detail, please? Or give a reference where this proof is explained in more detail.

It’s possible you’ve misunderstood ; the sections after that bit are all part of the machinery of the proof. See corollary 2.34 for the final proof. It actually takes a whole lot more work

@SBK I had the same initial reaction, but then I noticed that the OP refers to the proof on page 12, which is the page number of Corollary 2.34.

This is a much more sophisticated use of ultraproducts than just applying Łoś's theorem to a first-order sentence. Chernikov spends the previous 5 pages setting up the technology for the measure-theoretic transfer that's happening here. So I think it's a bit unfair to describe the details as "handwaved away".
Here's how the proof works:

If the theorem is false, then there is a $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence of finite graphs $G_i = (V_i,E_i)$ with $\lim_{i\to \infty}|V_i| = \infty$ such that $G_i$ has no $\varepsilon$-regular partition.
We take the ultraproduct $G = (V,E)$ by a non-principal ultrafilter $U$, and we use the ultralimit construction (described in the previous sections) to turn the counting measures on $\mathcal{P}(V_i)$ and $\mathcal{P}(V_i^2)$ into f.a.p. measures $\mu$ and $\mu'$ on the boolean algebras of internal subsets of $V$ and $V^2$.
We apply Theorem 2.32 to obtain a $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$-regular (according to $\mu$ and $\mu'$) finite partition of $G$ into internal sets.
Now for a contradiction, we want to obtain a $\varepsilon$-regular partition of $G_i$ on a $U$-large set of $i$. Here the definition of internal and the ultralimit construction of the measures is crucial. An internal set $S\subseteq V$ is itself the ultraproduct of a family of subsets $S_i\subseteq V_i$ for all $i$. So our partition of $G$ into finitely many pieces induces a partition of each $G_i$ (on a $U$-large set of $i$) into the same finite number of pieces. And the definitions of the measures $\mu$ and $\mu'$ as ultralimits of counting measures imply that on a $U$-large set of $i$, the induced partitions of $G_i$ are $\varepsilon$-regular.

I've really just repeated the proof written in the notes. But I'm not sure what else to say, because you haven't specified which part of the argument you find unclear. I hope that by emphasizing that you should unwind the definitions of internal set and ultralimit, you can settle your question for yourself. But feel free to ask for more details in the comments if there's a point where you're stuck.

In the comments, you asked "How exactly do we go from the partition of $G$ to the partition of $G_i$?"
Note that to make the proof work, we only need a partition of $G_i$ on a $U$-large set of indices $i$.
Let $X^1,\dots,X^k$ be a partition of $G$, where each $X^j$ is an internal set. Then, by definition of internal, for each $1\leq j\leq k$, there is a family $(X_i^j)_{i\in \omega}$ such that $\prod_{i\in \omega} X_i^j / U = X^j$. We want to check that for a $U$-large set of $i\in \omega$, $X^1_i,\dots,X^k_i$ is a partition of $G_i$.
Here we can use Łoś's Theorem. Let $L'$ be the language of graphs expanded by new unary predicates $P_1,\dots,P_k$. Note that if we expand $G$ to $G'$ by interpreting $P_j$ as $X^j$, and we expand each $G_i$ to $G_i'$ by interpreting $P_j$ as $X_i^j$, then $\prod_{i\in \omega}G_i'/U = G'$.
Let $\varphi$ be the $L'$-sentence asserting that the $P_j$ form a partition: $$\forall x\, \left(\bigvee_{1\leq j\leq k} \left(P_j(x)\land \bigwedge_{j'\neq j} \lnot P_{j'}(x)\right)\right).$$
Then $G\models \varphi$, so by Łoś's Theorem, $\{i\in \omega\mid G_i\models \varphi\}\in U$, and for all $i$ in this set, $X^1_i,\dots,X^k_i$ is a partition of $G_i$.

How exactly do we go from the partition of $G$ to the partition of $G_i$? I'm thinking about projections from all members of $[f]$ and taking them as one set of the partition, but this doesn't seem right, since maybe there are different $[f]$ and $[g]$ which are not within same equivalence class of the partition, but their images under the projections are the same. I think I have figured out everything else, thank you. Just this detail somehow seems unclear to me.

@tses I updated my answer to address your question.

Thank you, everything is clear now.
